# In R, how can I view and count unique entries in a column of a data set?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I need to pull out only the names of the cities in this data set: 
[image: the data set]

what command would I use to do that?

Comment: yes, names within the column "city"

Comment: Since `cities` is stored as a factor, you may also want to have a look at `levels(cities$city)` to retrieve the names of the cities (but not the frequency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
unique(cities$city)
```

You can also view the frequency that each city name occurred with:

```
table(cities$city)
```

Here's a demo with sample data:

```
cities <- c("New York","New York", "Los Angeles", "Boston", "Los Angeles")

unique(cities)
[1] "New York"    "Los Angeles" "Boston"

table(cities)
cities
     Boston Los Angeles    New York 
          1           2           2
```

Comment: is there another way to get those names out, say to include duplicates if there were any?

Comment: Are you trying to store them into a vector or count the frequency of each?

Comment: i would like to know how to count them, thanks bigly